# how to find lowest vertical and horizontal DCT coefficient of an image block

Tags: matlab, dct

I have an image of size 256x256 and it is divided into equal non overlapping blocks of size 8x8. I have to find the lowest vertical and horizontal DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform)coefficients of each image block. Is there any method available for this problem in MATLAB?

Comment: What's your definition of a "horizontal coefficient" in a 2D DCT? Are we talking about the output of [`dct2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dct2.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to create an array of indices that maps from the most important to the least important as you have stored them.

[image]

This is the pattern used in JPEG. What we don't know is how you have  arranged your coefficients so we cannot give you the ordering.